# EJBDeploy: RMIC Command failed on this project

Tags: java, ant, ejb, ibm-was

I'm trying to execute ejbdeploy.bat on an EAR file using the following command:

```
    <property name="EJB.SCRIPT" value="${wasdir}\ejbdeploy.bat ${tempdir}\tmp_ai_bpi.ear ${build.rmic.dir} ${deldir}\${out.ear}.ear -novalidate -quiet"/>               
        <shellscript shell="cmd.exe" dir="${projectdir}" tmpsuffix=".bat" inputstring="${EJB.SCRIPT}" failonerror="true">
              <env key="PATH" path="${env.WAS_HOME}/bin"/>                  
              <arg value="/c"/>
              <arg value="call"/>
            </shellscript>
```

The above is in an ant script. I'm using Windows 8, Java 1.7 and WAS 8.5.5. I'm getting the below error trace. I don't get any information in the pointed log file.

```
[shellscript] Current OS is Windows 8
[shellscript] Setting environment variable: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin
[shellscript] Executing 'cmd.exe' with arguments:
[shellscript] '/c'
[shellscript] 'call'
[shellscript] 'C:\Users\bnp\AppData\Local\Temp\script1775601837.bat'
[shellscript]
[shellscript] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
[shellscript] not part of the command.

[shellscript] C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\delivery>C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin\ejbdeploy.bat C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\tmp\lib\tmp_ai_bpi.ear C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\delivery\java\lib\ai_bpi.ear -novalidate -quiet
[shellscript] EJB Deploy configuration directory: c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\configuration/
[shellscript] framework search path: c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins
[shellscript] build:RAD851-I20121103_1921
[shellscript] okToInvokeInJVM true
[shellscript] okToInvokeInJVM true

[shellscript] Apr 27, 2016 3:57:39 PM com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.logging.Logger logInfo
[shellscript] INFO: project name is: ai_bpi
[shellscript] Apr 27, 2016 3:57:39 PM com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.logging.Logger logInfo
[shellscript] INFO: RMIC command was: -extdirs 


[shellscript] INFO: RMIC command was: -extdirs 
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\endorsed_apis\jaxws-api.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\endorsed_apis\jaxb-api.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\endorsed_apis\javax.j2ee.annotation.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\bin\compressedrefs\jclSC170\vm.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\se-service.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\math.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\jlm.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmorb.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmorbapi.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmcfw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmpkcs.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmcertpathfw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmjgssfw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmjssefw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmsaslfw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmjcefw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmjgssprovider.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmjsseprovider2.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmcertpathprovider.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\xmldsigfw.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\xml.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\charsets.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\resources.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\rt.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ibmgpu.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\batchboot.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ext\iwsorbutil.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\eclipse\plugins\j2ee.javax_1.4.0;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.eclipse_1.0.0;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\dev\javaee5.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\classes;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedChannels;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\ext;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\web\help;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\runtime; -classpath 
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\ai_bpi\build\classes;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\jdom.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\ac-4tcore-api.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\commons-codec-1.7.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\commons-lang-2.3.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\log4j.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\pskcxmlbeans.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\xbean.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\tmp_ai_bpi.ear\EarContent\xmlpublic.jar;
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\ai_bpi\ImportedClasses; -iiop -always -d 
C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\ai_bpi\build\classes 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.DeviceManagerHome 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.CredentialManagerHome 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.DeviceManager
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.AssetManager 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.CredentialManager 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.AuthenticatorManagerHome 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.AssetManagerHome 
    com.aspace.ftress.interfaces.ejb.UserManagerHome 

   [shellscript] Apr 27, 2016 12:56:12 PM com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.logging.Logger logInfo
[shellscript] INFO: additional RMIC options are: null
[shellscript] Apr 27, 2016 12:56:12 PM com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.logging.Logger logInfo
[shellscript] INFO: JreExtensionDirectories are: 
[Same jars as above]
[shellscript] Apr 27, 2016 12:56:12 PM com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.logging.Logger logErrorStatus
[shellscript] SEVERE: Error generating RMI code: RMIC command failed on project: ai_bpi with message:

[shellscript] Further details have  been recorded in the .log file in C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\.metadata.    [shellscript]                                                                                [*Error] An unexpected exception was thrown.  Halting execution.
[shellscript] Error generating RMI code: RMIC command failed on project: ai_bpi with message:

[shellscript] Further details have  been recorded in the .log file in C:\Workspace\BPI\cust.bnp.bpi\cust.bnp.bpi\BUILD\websphere\tmp\ear\ai_bpi._\.metadata.

\ws_rmi_compile.xml:35: shellscript returned: 1
    at     

org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:537)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:269)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:301)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:328)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1215)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1063)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:632)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:183)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:197)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:56)
```

Please help.